# Retrieving and Using a Value selected in a ComboBox

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml, combobox

GOAL: I have a GUI and a combo box with four values.
I am attempting to get the selected amount and have it print to a file with an associated colour.

For example: if "ABC" is selected, then in a file, "Value and Assigned Color ABC red" is written to the line.

I am having this issue because I do not know how to retrieve the value from that combo box to use in my GetHeader class.

EXTRA: I am looking for one of two solutions,

(1) I go through and do the string compare as seen in "retrieveValueFromBox," or

(2) somehow get the index of the selected item and use that index to write the line I need."
It would also be great to get some decent suggestions on how to work with or learn C# better.

My code:

MainWindow.xaml

```
<ComboBox x:Name="myBox" ...alignment information...>
  <ComboBoxItem Content="abc" ...alignment information...>
  <ComboBoxItem Content="def" ...alignment information...>
  <ComboBoxItem Content="ghi" ...alignment information...>
  <ComboBoxItem Content="jkl" ...alignment information...>
</ComboBox>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
private void selectedItemFromBox(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  ComboBox selectedValue = (ComboBox)sender;
  string selectedText = selectedValue.Text;
  OutputFile output = new OutputFile();
  output.retreiveValueFromBox(selectedText);
}
```

OutputFile.cs

```
namespace myApplication
{
  class OutputFile
  {
    // Stuff
  }


  //public bool Write( ...args...  ) makes the call to this function.  See below
  private void GetHeader(StreamWriter w, string year, string evt)
  {
    //How do I get the value from the combobox here so I can use it.
    // If it is better practice to grab the value in public bool Write() then see below
    //  Yes I understand that GetHEader's args will need to be changed

    w.WriteLine("Line 1");
    w.WriteLine("Line 2");
    w.WriteLine("Value and Assigned Color " + retreiveValueFromBox(comboBoxItem));
    w.WriteLine("Line N");

  }

  private string retreiveValueFromBox(string boxText)
  {
    string value_Color = "";

    //If I can just get the index of the string, I can just do a case/switch.  
    //And dump the String.Euals()

    
    if (String.Equals(boxText, "abc"))
    {
      value_Color = boxText + " red");
    }
    else if bString.Equals(boxText, "def")
    {
      value_Color = boxText + " blue");
    }
    else if String.Equals(boxText, "ghi")
    {
      value_Color = boxText + " green");
    }
    else if String.Equals(boxText, "jkl")
    {
      value_Color = boxText + " orange");
    }
    else 
    {
      value_Color = "UNKNOWN yellow");
    }

    return value_Color;
  }


  public bool Write( ...args...  )
  {

    //Stuff
    for (; idx < eventNum; )
    {

      // Or Get the ComboBox Value here

      GetHeader(sWrite, year(), evt); //And pass value in here.
    

    }


}
```

Comment: SelectedItem is a ComboBoxItem.  [ComboBoxItem.Content](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.contentcontrol.content?view=winrt-19041#Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_ContentControl_Content) should return the value.

Comment: Can you please expand on this a little more?

Comment: Got it almost.  "System.Windows.Controls.ComboBox.Item:" prints with the value.  The event handler only contains the line "comboBoxValue = myComboBoxName.SelectedItem.ToString();".  I'm assuming I'm using the incorrect "Selected___" thing.  Once it is 100% will post solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got what I needed.

Problems on my end.

The Combo Box was not tied to an event properly.  The fix was double clicking the Combo Box in the XAML design window, which created an event, at the very bottom of WindowWindow.xaml.cs, that tied to the box.

```
private void myComboBoxName_SelectionChanged(Object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
  comboxValue = myComboBoxName.SelectedIndex.ToString();
}
```

I noticed, which I did not before, there was another function dealing with information from the GUI (File I/O information).  So I put the variable "comboboxValue" into that function, and kept passing it though, until it took me all the way into the Outputfile.cs.

Since I was only working with the Index (0, 1, 2, 3, 4).  I just used a Case/Switch to print out the value and the assigned color.

Comment: Seems issue has been resolved. Maybe you can mark it as the answer.